# Is it possible to customize CrashDialog in Crashlytics?

Tags: java, android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am using Fabric Crashlytics in my app. And I need to display my own crash report dialog while my app is catching crash. I didn't find any mechanisms of how to do that with the help of stock Crashlytics dialog. I need to display my own dialog because I need to collect users emails to get from them feedback according crashes

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's not possible to customize the dialog but in the Firebase console under crash section you can spot easily who the crash belongs to.

You only need to set User Id and/or User email

Doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#set_user_ids

Once you get the email you can contact the user directly.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer) Sorry, but I am using Fabric IO Crashlytics console. And I din't find there such params

Comment: The sdk should be the same ... Only different UI where you can find the user email.